# jstree disable_node not working when id is string

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core, jquery-plugins, jstree

I want to disable some nodes in jstree plugin. I used the following code for this purpose and everything was fine.

```
var tidlist = ['17f6171a-4da6-4904-ae75-c290eb101717', '3fbb9e60-13f2-48e9-9323-003cb46dbb5d'];
for (var i = 0; i < tidlist.length; i++)
{
    $.jstree.reference('#jstree1').disable_node(tidlist[i]);
}
```

In this example, the IDs are defined as fixed. But the IDs are not fixed and come from the controller.

**Controller**

```
ViewBag.rlist = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tQuery.Select(t => t.CenterUserID).ToList());
```

**View**

```
var tidlist = [];
tidlist = '@ViewBag.rlist';
for (var i = 0; i < tidlist.length; i++)
{
    $.jstree.reference('#jstree1').disable_node(tidlist[i]);
}
```

But this code does not work.

Comment: Did you check what does `@ViewBag.rlist` has ?  Also , check if `tidlist[i]` has the required values or not .

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the break point the debug the JavaScript via F12 developer tools, then, you can see the `tidlist` value should be `System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String];`, instead of the string array.

The issue is that we can't directly access the ViewBag value in the JavaScript.

To transfer the string array from controller to JavaScript script, first, in the controller, convert the array or list to a string (with separator), then, in the View page, use a hidden field to store the ViewBag value, finally, in the JavaScript script, get value from the hidden field and call the Split () method to convert the string value to an array.

Code as below:

Controller:

```
var strlist = new List<string>() { "17f6171a-4da6-4904-ae75-c290eb101717", "3fbb9e60-13f2-48e9-9323-003cb46dbb5d" }; 
ViewBag.rlist = string.Join(',', strlist);
```

View Page:

```
<div id="jstree">
    <!-- in this example the tree is populated from inline HTML -->
    <ul>
        <li>
            Root node 1
            <ul>
                <li id="17f6171a-4da6-4904-ae75-c290eb101717">Child node 1</li>
                <li>Child node 2</li>
                <li id="3fbb9e60-13f2-48e9-9323-003cb46dbb5d">Child node 3</li>
                <li>Child node 4</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Root node 2</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<button>demo button</button>
<input type="hidden" id="myInput" data-myValue="@ViewBag.rlist" />
@section Scripts{
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.2.1/themes/default/style.min.css" /> 
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.2.1/jstree.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            // 6 create an instance when the DOM is ready
            $('#jstree').jstree();
            // 7 bind to events triggered on the tree
            $('#jstree').on("changed.jstree", function (e, data) {
                console.log(data.selected);
            });
            // 8 interact with the tree - either way is OK
            $('button').on('click', function () {
                // var tidlist = ['17f6171a-4da6-4904-ae75-c290eb101717', '3fbb9e60-13f2-48e9-9323-003cb46dbb5d']; 
                var tidlist = $("#myInput").attr("data-myValue").split(","); //the result is an string array, like: ['17f6171a-4da6-4904-ae75-c290eb101717', '3fbb9e60-13f2-48e9-9323-003cb46dbb5d']
                for (var i = 0; i < tidlist.length; i++) {
                    $.jstree.reference('#jstree').select_node(tidlist[i]);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

The result as below:

[image]